# Cannot find function readDICOM, though oro.dicom is installed

Tags: r, dicom

I am struggeling with reading DICOM files in R. I have installed the oro.dicom package, using:

```
install.packages("oro.dicom", repos="https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/")
```

I have set the working directory to where the files are located.

When trying to read a dicom file, using...

```
slice=readDICOM("IM-0001-0011.dcm")
```

... I get the following error message:

```
Error: could not find function "readDICOM"
```

Can someone help?
Thank you, 
Lena

Comment: Did you do `library(oro.dicom)` (I think so, but you never know :P)? If yes, try `slice=oro.dicom::readDICOM("IM-0001-0011.dcm")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load package with `library(oro.dicom)` fisrt before you will use functions from that package,